# carbon к дате прибавить время

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

как получить дату прибавив к текущей 72 часа?

Comment: Добавьте код в ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$date->addHours(72);
```